# serialVersionUID in Java

Tags: java, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serialization version uid in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241554/serialization-version-uid-in-java)

We know that Java serialization mechanism ignore static fields. If it is this, then how the deserializer knows the serialVersionUID of the serializer. serialVersionUID is always a static field of the class to be serialized. Thank you for your help.

cheng

Comment: @jalopaba Thank you for your reminding. Maybe there are ways to merge the two questions.

Comment: The weird thing is I got a downvote in my answer in the other question :-)

Comment: Too bad... I found your answer useful and vote it up.

Comment: "We know that Java serialization mechanism ignore static fields." 
No we don't. We know that it *doesn't serialize* static fields. Not the same thing. And *obviously* the `serialVersionUID` field gets special treatment. Not a serious question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `serializedVersionUID` *is written to the stream*, even though it is static.

It is then used on deserialization to compare it against the one in the currently available version of the class.

Note that it is not written as part of every instance, but as part of the "ObjectStreamClass" that defines the class for all instances in the stream that want to use it.

Comment: Can you provide your reference to official java docs?

Comment: BTW, is it the only static field written to the stream?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#8299  Also see the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

The `Class` that is deserialized is in the `Classpath` so all that data is known.

Update (thanks to @Thilo):

```
"and equally importantly, the serializedVersionUID is written to the stream, even though it is static." – Thilo
```

Answer (score 0):

`serialVersionUID` is retrieved from the class not stored  instance of a "serialized" object.it is "stored" in the compiled bytecode if it is defined otherwise it is computed using some algo.

Refer below byte code of class that implements `Serializable` interface.