# serialVersionUID android

Tags: java, android

I have uploaded a new release of my app to play store. When my clients tries to update to the newer version they get the following

`com.rio.g.l; Incompatible class (SUID): com.rio.g.l: static final long serialVersionUID =5129006085660760312L; but expected com.rio.g.l: static final long serialVersionUID =0L;`

When I install the same apk file via adb, it is working fine. Why does this error occur? How can I solve this error in the play store?

Comment: Is the class `com.rio.g.l` your own class or is it from a library that you are using?

Comment: its my own class. but because of progaurd it is showing like this.

Comment: This problem occurs when you have serialized an object earlier when your class had `serialVersionUID=0L` and after publishing the update, the same class has `serialVersionUID=5129006085660760312L`. This value may be computed by your JVM, if not explicitly provided in the code. That is why it is a good practice to initialize `serialVersionUID` field manually in your serializable classes. Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: For ProGuard issue, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210831/serialization-deserialization-proguard

Comment: Thanks for explaination, but Right now my new apk already uploaded on store. so, can how can I prevent my user from getting this error?

Comment: Push another update and roll `serialVersionUID` back to `0L`.

Comment: I tried it local but it's not working. I have replace serialVersionUID with 0L.

Comment: You will have to change your class so that it has `serialVersionUID=0L` and re-release your app. Unless proguard has renamed different class before to `com.rio.g.l` and different class now. You should add classes that you serialize -> deserialize to be skipped by proguard.

Comment: okay let me try to change class name

Comment: @dev Don't use proguard, build the app and see whether it's still not working. It is likely that proguard previously renamed some other class to `com.rio.g.l` in which case the serialisation will fail.
If it works without proguard, you have to add the classes that you serialize ---> deserialize to the list of skipped classes by proguard.